# Posting Json as Entity with scalaj-http

Tags: json, scala, rest

the api of scalaj-http is clean and I would like to use it for a new project, but it usually post a Json in StringEntity as parameter, like this

```
        JSONObject TokenRequest = new JSONObject()
            .put("Credentials", new JSONObject()
                .put("Username",  username)
                .put("Password",  password));

        StringEntity requestBody = new StringEntity(TokenRequest.toString());

        httppost.setEntity(requestBody);
```

Not sure if it doable with scalaj-http?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to their [github page](https://github.com/scalaj/scalaj-http#post-raw-arraybyte-or-string-data-and-get-response-code) you need to set the `content-type` header to `application/json` to send the body as json.

```
Http(url).postData(data).header("content-type", "application/json").asString.code
```

Comment: Thanks, how do I get that "data" in form of byte?

Comment: if you mean the data which is being posted, you can try `data.getBytes` after you convert it to string.

Comment: what encoding should I put? UTF-8?

Comment: Thanks, get it, it doesn't matter

Comment: how do I pass the string variable as placeholder inside postData? like this way: .postData(s"""{"Name": $name, "Title": $title}""") ? but it doesnt work.